# Black out area of Google Maps activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'd like to "black out" certain locations on a google map in an android app. I'd like to be able to pull location information that would be loaded onto the screen, and just determine whether or not I want to load that segment of the map, or replace it with a black block.

Is this supported by the maps api? Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Ground Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay) in Android Maps API. It will let you overlay (or black out) any section of the map based on coordinates.

So if you have a list of locations and their coordinates, you should be able to overlay with a custom image on top of those areas. It [has custom options](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay.html) to automatically scale or anchor the image bounds.